# Mobius transformation : $ \frac{az+ b}{cz+d}$ with $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{C}$ for $U= \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : Im z>0\}$, then show $a,b,c,d$ are real

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

Let $U= \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : Im z>0\}$. Let

\begin{align}
  u(z) = \frac{az+ b}{cz+d}
\end{align}
with $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{C}$ and $u: U \rightarrow U$ one to one and onto, 
What i want to prove is that $a,b,c,d,$ are real.

TA says, $u(0)$ is real thus $\frac{b}{d}$ is real. But i do not understand why $u(0)$ is real.

I think $z=0=0+0i$ thus $z=0$ is not in $U$, but how can be defined? and be real?

Any other idea or method for proving $a,b,c,d,$ are real will be helpful.

Comment: I think it's probably okay to replace '>' with $\geq$ without changing the spirit of the problem. Then since your Mobius transformation is a bijection on the upper half plane, and Mobius transforms send circles to circles (and lines to lines) you can ask what it does to the real line. If it rotates it, it leaves the upper half plane. If it lifts it, it wouldn't be surjective (and similarly if it takes it to any other kind of circle). Your transform should send the real line to itself then. So this settles the first question.

Comment: Then I would say to use the cross-ratio in order to show all the coefficients are real. This formula describes a Mobius transformation based on what it does to three points, but all that matters is that those points are real, and that the cross-ratio is preserved by Mobius transforms, so you could just write any three real numbers, perhaps $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$, and choose easy numbers for them to map to, like $-1, 0, 1$. Then you could perhaps solve for the transformation explciitly, and observe that all the coefficients are some combination of the real numbers above.